# Doing BFS of a 2D array on C++

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic-arrays, breadth-first-search

I have a 2D 256x256 image array in which I have to do a BFS to find the dimensions of a character somewhere in the bmp image. I have to check the 8 connected neighbors. What additional arrays do I need to do this? BFS queue array, predicessor array, etc... The image is white(255) and the characters in the image are black(0). I am using C++. Thanks.

Comment: If you need a queue, you use `std::queue`.

Comment: I dont have code for that part yet since I am not sure how to start  it.

Comment: Do you know what a BFS is? Which pixel do you start from? It doesn't sound very complicated if you apply your brain a little.